# Android SQLite Foreign Key Syntax Error

Tags: android, database, sqlite, foreign-keys, syntax-error

I'm just starting to play around with SQLite databases in Android apps. I'm trying to make a 'team' table, and a 'player' table, and I want the 'player' table to have a foreign key which references the 'team' table's auto-increment _ID field (I think this _ID field comes from implementing BaseColumns in my contract class). I thought I had the syntax correct but I get the following error (even after uninstalling and reinstalling my app)

```
06-08 20:26:22.763: E/Database(29843): Failure 1 (near "playerName": syntax error) on 0x22a110 when preparing 'CREATE TABLE player (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,team_ID INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY(team_ID) REFERENCES team(_id), playerName TEXT,playerAge INTEGER,playerPosition TEXT,playerHeight REAL,playerWeight REAL,playerPhoto TEXT,playerNumber INTEGER)'.
```

The error above shows the SQL statement that ends up trying to go through. This is the code for making the SQL statement (sorry it's unnecessarily wordy, I was following a tutorial):

```
private static final String SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES = "CREATE TABLE "
        + TeamTable.TABLE_NAME + " (" + TeamTable._ID
        + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + TeamTable.COLUMN_NAME_TEAM_NAME
        + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP + TeamTable.COLUMN_NAME_TEAM_WINS
        + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP + TeamTable.COLUMN_NAME_TEAM_LOSSES
        + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP + TeamTable.COLUMN_NAME_TEAM_LOGO
        + TEXT_TYPE + " )";

private static final String SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES_2 = "CREATE TABLE "
        + PlayerTable.TABLE_NAME + " (" + PlayerTable._ID
        + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + "team_ID INTEGER, "
        + "FOREIGN KEY(team_ID) REFERENCES team(_id), "
        + PlayerTable.COLUMN_NAME_PLAYER_NAME + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP
        + PlayerTable.COLUMN_NAME_PLAYER_AGE + " INTEGER" + COMMA_SEP
        + PlayerTable.COLUMN_NAME_PLAYER_POSITION + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP
        + PlayerTable.COLUMN_NAME_PLAYER_HEIGHT + " REAL" + COMMA_SEP
        + PlayerTable.COLUMN_NAME_PLAYER_WEIGHT + " REAL" + COMMA_SEP
        + PlayerTable.COLUMN_NAME_PLAYER_PHOTO + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP
        + PlayerTable.COLUMN_NAME_PLAYER_NUMBER + " INTEGER" + ")";
```

Then I use `execSQL(SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES)` and `execSQL(SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES_2`, and the error appears. I have tried creating only the 'team' table and it seems to work okay. I'm even able to read some data from the 'team' table and display the value in a TextView. But when the 'player' table is introduced things stop working. I am probably missing something very obvious but I can't seem to find it.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Declare first all the columns and put the `FOREIGN KEY(team_ID) REFERENCES team(_id)` after the last column.

So the final query is like

```
CREATE TABLE player
(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
team_ID INTEGER, 
playerName TEXT,
playerAge INTEGER,
playerPosition TEXT,
playerHeight REAL,
playerWeight REAL,
playerPhoto TEXT,
playerNumber INTEGER,
FOREIGN KEY(team_ID) REFERENCES team(_id));
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I had a feeling it was something simple like this. Things are working great now! I accepted this answer and tried to Vote Up but I need more reputation. Thanks again!!